# Comparing rows in 2 dataframes and counting number of similar columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes

```
>> df1
ID  Hair  Legs  Feathers
 1    1     0      0
 2    1     2      1
 3    0     2      1

>> df2
ID  Hair  Legs  Feathers
21   1      2     0
22   1      0     1
```

I want to compare each row in `df2` with all the rows in `df1` and count the number of columns that are similar in each row of `df2` in such a manner that it gives the following dataframe `df3`

```
>> df3
ID    Hair  Legs  Feathers  Count
1-21   1      2      0        2
2-21   1      2      0        2
3-12   1      2      0        1
1-22   1      0      1        2
2-22   1      0      1        2
3-22   1      0      1        1
```

The `Count` is calculated in such a manner that the first row of `df2` is compared with the first row of `df1` and the number of similar columns are calculated. Similarly between the first row of `df2` with second row of `df1` and so on. Moreover, the second row of `df2` is compared with all the rows of `df1` one by one and stored in another dataframe `df3`.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Why output for second row `22   1      0     1` is not in output `DataFrame` ?

Comment: @jezrael I just added the output for the second row of `df2` to the output `DataFrame`

Comment: ID values are unique in both DataFrames?

Comment: Yes, the ID values are unique for each row in each DataFrame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
#cross join between both DataFrames
df = df2.assign(A=1).merge(df1.assign(A=1), on='A', suffixes=('','_')).drop('A', axis=1)
#join ID columns and set index
df.index = df.pop('ID_').astype(str) + '_' + df.pop('ID').astype(str)
df.index.name='ID'
print (df)
      Hair  Legs  Feathers  Hair_  Legs_  Feathers_
ID                                                 
1_21     1     2         0      1      0          0
2_21     1     2         0      1      2          1
3_21     1     2         0      0      2          1
1_22     1     0         1      1      0          0
2_22     1     0         1      1      2          1
3_22     1     0         1      0      2          1
```

---

```
cols = df.filter(regex='_$').columns
#compare rows for match and count True values by sum
df['count'] = df[cols.str[:-1]].eq(df[cols].rename(columns=lambda x: x[:-1])).sum(axis=1)

df = df.drop(cols, axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
     ID  Hair  Legs  Feathers  count
0  1_21     1     2         0      2
1  2_21     1     2         0      2
2  3_21     1     2         0      1
3  1_22     1     0         1      2
4  2_22     1     0         1      2
5  3_22     1     0         1      1
```

Comment: thank you so much it neatly did the required job. Really appreciated.